# How to let electron app open all links started with "http://" or "https://" and with target="_blank" open in browser instead in app

Tags: node.js, browser, hyperlink, electron, href

How to let electron app open all links beginning with "http://" or "https://" and at the same time with target="_blank" open in browser instead in app

I want it without additional modules like [node-open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open)

(sry for my English, google translator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const shell = nodeRequire('electron').shell

$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="http"][target="_blank"]', function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    shell.openExternal(this.href);
});
```

is working as well, but only if I click on link by left button, but if I click by wheel, it do shit....

so new queston: **How can I open link in external browser if I click by wheel?**

Comment: can this be made in node.js instead of jQuery ?

Comment: to answer the question in the answer, you can use the mousedown event instead

Answer (score 0):

Use the "shell" module provided by electron -

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell

```
 const {shell} = require('electron')

shell.openExternal('https://github.com')
```

You need to listen to on click handler of a button or link tag and implement this